# Get Key Name from Model State/ Model State Dictionary?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am wondering how do I get the key name from Model Sate or Model State Dictionary.

When you add a error to the dictionary

```
  modelStateDictionary.AddModelError("key","errorMessage");
```

you have to specify a key.

I want to get the key name.

```
 foreach (ModelState modelState in modelStateDictionary.Values) 
            {



            }
```

I did the above but that only contains the error message I want to know what the key of that was. I only can find to get all keys that gets stored in a list of strings. I want to get it out each time I go through the foreach loop. So can I not get a key name by index or something?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can also enumerate the [.Keys property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt2fy5zk%28VS.80%29.aspx)

```
foreach (var key in modelStateDictionary.Keys) 
        {
            ModelState modelState = modelStateDictionary[key];
        }
```

Comment: Very Clever solution :)

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> pair in modelStateDictionary)
{
        // You get key and value
           pair.Value;
           pair.Key;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach (var kvp in modelStateDictionary)
{
    var key = kvp.Key;
    var value = kvp.Value;

    // do something with key and/or value
}
```